# Flattening and Replacing Object Field in Lodash/Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have the following data which contains nested fields. 
I'm currently using a For loop to replace nested fields but it seems very archaic.

I want to flatten the nested fields to the key of name from this:

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": Sally,
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Chile"
        },
        "city": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Santiago"
        },
        "city-spot": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Downtown",
        },
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": Tom,
        "country": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Canada"
        },
        "city": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Vancouver"
        },
        "city-spot": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Downtown",
        }
    }
]
```

Into this:

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": Sally,
        "country": "Chile",
        "city": "Santiago",
        "city-spot": "Downtown",
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": Tom,
        "country": "Canada",
        "city": "Vancouver",
        "city-spot": "Downtown",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#map` each object in the array, and `_.mapValues()` it to the flattened form:

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"name":"Sally","country":{"id":1,"name":"Chile"},"city":{"id":1,"name":"Santiago"},"city-spot":{"id":1,"name":"Downtown"}},{"id":2,"name":"Tom","country":{"id":3,"name":"Canada"},"city":{"id":2,"name":"Vancouver"},"city-spot":{"id":5,"name":"Downtown"}}];

var result = data.map(function(o) {
  return _.mapValues(o, function(value) {
    return _.get(value, 'name', value); // if name found in value return name, if not return value
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like the `mapValues()` approach. You can simplify the callback by using `_.get()`. It would look something like `return _.get(value, 'name', value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need lodash, underscore. You can do it using Array#map.

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sally",
    "country": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Chile"
    },
    "city": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Santiago"
    },
    "city-spot": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Downtown",
    },
},

    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tom",
        "country": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Canada"
        },
        "city": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Vancouver"
        },
        "city-spot": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Downtown",
        }
    }
];
//iterate to generate
var modData = data.map(function(d){
   return {
       "id": d.id,
       "name": d.name,
       "country": d.country.name,
       "city": d.city.name,
       "city-spot": d["city-spot"].name
   }
});
console.log(modData);
```